# Plone Theme without requirements

Tags: themes, plone

I'm looking for a way to create a Plone theme without any extra tools required. As a wordpress user I was going to use the native sunburst theme and modify it (but as a full theme not a child).

I created an egg and tried to extract the essentials* from the sunburst theme.

**(the browser folder and parts of the configure.zcml, in order to have a "mytheme" tag under the [Site Setup>Themes] selection)*

For some reason that didn't work. I am able to activate the "add-on" but nothing else happens..any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question but my final solution to the problem was:

```
[terminal-prompt]:src: ../bin/paster create -t   plone3_theme
Selected and implied templates:
    ZopeSkel#basic_namespace  A   basic Python project with a namespace package
    ZopeSkel#plone            A   project for Plone add-ons
    ZopeSkel#plone3_theme     A   theme for Plone 3

Enter project name: plonetheme.[project]
Variables:
    egg:      plonetheme.[project]
    package:  plonetheme[project]
    project:  plonetheme.[project]

Expert Mode? (What question mode would you like? (easy/expert/all)?) ['easy']: all
Namespace Package Name (Name of outer namespace package) ['plonetheme']:
Package Name (Name of the inner namespace package) ['[project]']:
Skin Name (Name of the theme (human facing, added to portal_skins)) ['']: [Project] Theme
Skin Base (Name of the theme from which this is copied) ['Plone Default']: [dependent on base theme]
Empty Styles? (Override default public stylesheets with empty ones?) [False]:
Include Documentation? (Include in-line documentation in generated code?) [True]:
Version (Version number for project) ['1.0']: 0.1.0
Description (One-line description of the project) ['An installable theme for Plone 3']: [description]
Register Profile (Should this package register a GS Profile) [True]:
Long Description (Multi-line description (in ReST)) ['']: [long description]
Author (Name of author for project) ['']: HSTS Web Development Center
Author Email (Email of author for project) ['']: support@example.com
Keywords (List of keywords, space-separated) ['web zope plone theme']:
Project URL (URL of the homepage for this project) ['http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/']: http://www.example.com
Project License (Name of license for the project) ['GPL']:
Zip-Safe? (Can this project be used as a zipped egg? (true/false)) [False]:
Zope2 Product? (Are you creating a product for Zope2/Plone or an Archetypes Product?) [True]:
```

[>>>SOURCE](http://www.healthsystem.virginia.edu/wdc/get-help/how-to/developer-guides/creating-a-plone-theme-product-plone-4)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a hassle-free way to create and use themes (Plone 4.x), I'd suggest you forget about the addon style and start working on [Diazo](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/index.html) themes.
A Diazo theme is just a zip file which you can easily upload to Plone and use.  No addon required.

You may also find [Codapress](http://plone.org/products/plonetheme.codapress) themes (which is designed using Diazo) as a good starting point --at least that's the way I learned it.

Answer (score 2):

In Plone 4.3, there is an in-Plone theme editor in the control panel, using Diazo technology. You can't modify Sunburst, but there is a sample theme based on Twitter Bootstrap that you can use for inspiration. If you're comfortable with HTML and CSS, the rest should be pretty easy.

There's detailed help available from that control panel as well.

Comment: You can modify Sunburst if you install plonetheme.diazo_sunburst first…